Enumerate Projected Construction Data and Dates to Current Dataset
I am attempting to project out a construction percentage to completion to visualize when a project may finish from where it is at. For example, if a project is 40% complete then I want to see on what date it may finish at 100%. Some relevant information: if the project is at 0% I want to then project the entirety of the project. If a project is at 95% or the NTP Date(start of construction) has not been reached yet then I don't need to project out.
Additionally, how a project increases is determined by what bucket it fits, for example, if a project is at 40% then I use the program pace of work field and use that value until it passes 60% then I use the next value within that construction bin range.
Here is my current code and would appreciate any feedback on anything that I am missing.
The data is stacked on top of each other so that if a project has multiple entries with all the same information except for different uploaded dates and cns%.
def calculate_projected_cns(adjusted_cns):
    cns_bins = [0,20,40,60,80,100]
    
    def calculated_projected_cns_per_project(group):
        last_updated_date = group['Uploaded Data Day'].max()
        last_cns_percent = group['CNS %'].max()
        
        if last_cns_percent == 0:
            return group
        
        if last_updated_date >=group['NTP_DT'].max() or group['Max CNS %'].max() > 95:
            return (group)
        
        bin_index = next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(cns_bins) if val > last_cns_percent)
        
        pace_of_work_column = f'CNS Bin {bin_index} - {bin_index - 20}'
        pace_of_work_value = group[pace_of_work_column].values[0]
                                   
        days_to_complete = (100 - last_cns_percent) / pace_of_work_value
        print("Days to Complete:", days_to_complete)
        
        projected_cns_increment = pace_of_work * days_to_complete
        print("Projected CNS Increment:", projected_cns_increment)
        
        projected_cns_percent = min(100, last_cns_percent + projected_cns_increment)
        print("Projected CNS %: " , projected_cns_percent)
        
        projceted_dates = pd.date_range(start = last_updated_date, periods = int(np.ceil(days_to_complete)), freq = 'MS'[1:])
                                   
        projected_df = pd.DataFrame({'Uploaded Data Day' : projected_dates, 
                                   'CNS %': projected_cns_percent,})
                                   
        return pd.concat([group], projected_df, ignore_index= True)
                                   
    df_with_projected_cns = adjusted_cns.groupby('Project Number').apply(calculated_projected_cns_per_project)
                                   
    return df_with_projected_cns

df_with_projected_cns = calculate_projected_cns(adjusted_cns.copy())

My current code:
def calculate_projected_cns(adjusted_cns):
    cns_bins = [0,20,40,60,80,100]
    
    def calculated_projected_cns_per_project(group):
        last_updated_date = group['Uploaded Data Day'].max()
        last_cns_percent = group['CNS %'].max()
        
        if last_cns_percent == 0:
            return group
        
        if last_updated_date >=group['NTP_DT'].max() or group['Max CNS %'].max() > 95:
            return (group)
        
        bin_index = next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(cns_bins) if val > last_cns_percent)
        
        pace_of_work_column = f'CNS Bin {bin_index} - {bin_index - 20}'
        pace_of_work_value = group[pace_of_work_column].values[0]
                                   
        days_to_complete = (100 - last_cns_percent) / pace_of_work_value
        print("Days to Complete:", days_to_complete)
        
        projected_cns_increment = pace_of_work * days_to_complete
        print("Projected CNS Increment:", projected_cns_increment)
        
        projected_cns_percent = min(100, last_cns_percent + projected_cns_increment)
        print("Projected CNS %: " , projected_cns_percent)
        
        projceted_dates = pd.date_range(start = last_updated_date, periods = int(np.ceil(days_to_complete)), freq = 'MS'[1:])
                                   
        projected_df = pd.DataFrame({'Uploaded Data Day' : projected_dates, 
                                   'CNS %': projected_cns_percent,})
                                   
        return pd.concat([group], projected_df, ignore_index= True)
                                   
    df_with_projected_cns = adjusted_cns.groupby('Project Number').apply(calculated_projected_cns_per_project)
                                   
    return df_with_projected_cns

df_with_projected_cns = calculate_projected_cns(adjusted_cns.copy())


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
